# Business logic exception.example

Tags: exception, n-tier-architecture

I have this scenario in my 3-tier app with a Service Layer that serves to a MVC presentation layer:

I have an operation that creates, for example, an Employee whose email must be unique in the set of Employees. This operation is executed in the MVC presentation layer through a service.

How do I manage the intent to create a Employee whose email is already registered in the Database for another Employee?

I am thinking in 2 options:

1) Have another operation that queries if there's an Employee with the same email given for the new Employee.

2) Throw an exception in the service CreateEmployee for the duplicate email.

I think it is a matter of what I think is best or most suitable for the problem.
I propose the 1) option because I think that this is a matter of validation.
But the 2) option only needs *1* call to the service, therefore its (?) more efficient.

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'Presentation' layer you really mean presentation, you should not be creating a new employee in that layer. You should only be preparing any data to be cleanly presented in the HTTP response object.

Generally a good way to think of this sort of problem is to consider what your service objects should do if called by a command-line program:

```
> createEmployee allison.brie@awesome.com
  Error! 'allison.brie@awesome.com' is already registered.
```

In this there is some terminal management layer that calls the service. The service does something to realize there is another user with the same email, and throws an appropriate exception (ie `DuplicateUserException`). Then the terminal management layer interprets that exception and prints out `"Error! " + exception.getMessage();`

That said, note that your two options are actually the same option. Your service must still query the database for the duplicate. While this is 'validation' it is not input validation. Input validation means checking to see if it's a valid email address. (Is there an '@' symbol and a valid TLD?)

Comment: I mean create an Employee from presentation layer.

I really like the point of view to resolve the problem.

I hadn't think that the CreateEmployee also has to query for the duplicate and that is really a problem. Because if I think in 2 transactions ExistsEmployee and CreateEmployee that executes secuentially the first one could have been succefful but the second one no, because in the middle another Employee could have been created, for example, by another user.

Thanks!

Comment: Your service layer should provide idempotent functionality to do the data manipulation they're specified for. The presentation layer should simply make a call to the service layer once it's validated the input as sensical. If there are business rules the input is bad, the service layer should report that - such as duplicate email addresses. The presentation layer should then just know how to handle the specified failure cases (ie each exception type).

Comment: I see.
I will mek the functionallity of the service layer idempotent as you said, I had forgotten or not really understood this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely go with second option:

- as you mentioned it avoids 1 call to the service
- it keeps your service interface clean with just one method for the employee creation
- it is consistant from a transactional point of view (an exception meaning "transaction failed"). Keep in mind that validation is not only one of the many reasons that can make the transaction fail.
- imagine your validation constraints evolve (ex: other employee attributes...), you won't want to make all you implementation evolve only for this.

Something to have in mind: Make sure to make your Exception verbose enough to identify clearly the cause of the failure.

Comment: I liked the 4 point in your recomendations.

I'm thinking in making custom exceptions in, initially, 2 groups
the DataAccessExceptions and the BusinessLogic exceptions.

Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, vote up :) Determining which kind of exception to throw can be tricky. From my experience, to keep it simple and evolutive, you often need only 2 types of exceptions thown by services: On stating that the service encountered a technical problem (could be InternalException because DataAccessException is often reserved to model layers) and the other one stating that we didn't meet the business requirements (BusinessLogicException seems good). In the BusinessLogicException, you could have a hash of errors (ex: `errors.put("email", "ALREADY_EXISTS")`)

Comment: Haha you read my mind! I have been trying to achive the implementation of a Custom ErrorHandling without success so far.
And one of my concerns was how many types of Exceptions should I been throwing.

I really appreciate your responses!

I will make one more question in SO because I really can't make ErrorHandler working.

Thanks!